# Economic Applications of Game Theory

Tags: game-theory, economics

I'm currently looking at this course in economic game theory.

However, when attempting this example:

> In this question you are asked to price a simpliﬁed version of 
>   mortgage-backed securities. A banker lends money to $n$ homeowners, where each 
>   homeowner signs a mortgage contract. According to the mortgage contract, the 
>   homeowner is to pay the lender 1 million dollar, but he may go bankrupt with 
>   probability $p$, in which case there will be no payment. There is also an investor 
>   who can buy a contract in which case he would receive the payment from the 
>   homeowner who has signed the contract. The utility function $u$ of the investor is 
>   given by $u(x) = −\text{exp}(−\alpha x)$, where $x$ is the net change in his wealth.

I could not seem to understand their solution:

> He pays a price $P$ if and only if $E[u(x−P)] ≥ u(0)$, i.e.,
>   $−(1 −p)\text{exp}(−\alpha (1 −P )) −p \text{exp}(−\alpha (0 −P)) ≥ −1$

Could someone please explain to me how they arrived at this?

I thought the function would've been:

$$-\text{exp}(\alpha(x-P)) \ge -1$$

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the same letter $P$ with two different meanings! In your formula, $P$ is used both for the price that the investor is willing to pay and for the probability that the homeowner goes bankrupt.

Comment: @PerManne oh sorry I will fix it then

Comment: downvote explain?

Comment: I did not downvote, but have you copied the solution faithfully? The right hand side should be $u(0)$ instead of $P(0)$, and $x$ does not have the same meaning in the problem and in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the investor does not know the value of $x$ when buying the contract, so $x$ cannot be part of the decision criterium.

If the investor is lucky, the contract will be repaid and the investor will make a profit of $1-P$. If he is unlucky, the homeowner will go bankrupt and the investor will lose $P$. The expected utility of buying the contract is $$(1-p)\cdot u(1-P) + p\cdot u(-P)$$
which is equal to the left hand side of your answer.

If the investor does not buy the contract, the utility is $u(0)=-1$, which is your right hand side.

Comment: Why is it $-P$ and not $P$?

Comment: A loss of $P$ is the same as a gain of $-P$.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks for the answer.